# Web Scraping within iframe using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, iframe, rvest

I am very new to rvest library and this is the first time that I am trying to scrape something. I am trying to scrape the very first table on this web page https://mup.gov.hr/promet-na-granicnim-prijelazima-282198/282198, that is titled PUTNICI (translated to PASSANGERS) within iframe, but I am struggling to do that.

In the top left corner, there is also a date option, that one can choose to select very specific day, month and year that one wants to see.
Is there any chance that I can scrape that very first table for specific time period, lets say whole January 2022, or if not, at least to scrape the very first table?

This is my code at the moment:

```
"https://mup.gov.hr/promet-na-granicnim-prijelazima-282198/282198" %>% 
 read_html() %>% 
 html_nodes("iframe") %>%
 extract(1) %>% 
 html_attr("src") %>% 
 read_html() %>% 
 html_node("#prometGranicniPrijelaz") %>% 
 html_text()
```

I would be really thankful if someone helped me on this subject!

Answer (score 0):

If you open your browser's Developer Tools - Network tab - fetch/Xhr and then change the date on the website you will see the request the happens in the backend that loads the data you are looking for. You can make your queries to that backend url and loop through the dates:

https://granica.mup.hr/default.inc.aspx?ajaxq=PrometPoDatumu&odDat=06.02.2022

https://granica.mup.hr/default.inc.aspx?ajaxq=PrometPoDatumu&odDat=07.02.2022

etc

I don't believe it's in an iframe but rather an HTML table with a `class = "desktop promet"` and you can parse the data you are looking for from there.

Comment: Much appreciate. Thanks!